# Mongoose update not updating: { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, crud

I have a collection named "permissions" on MongoDB.
I want to implement a simple update like this:

```
let schema = new Schema({
    title: String
  });
  let Permissions = mongoose.model("Permission", schema);
  let permission = new Permissions();

  let query = {};
  let newValues = {
    $set: {
      title: "Yes"
    }
  };
  permission.updateOne(query, newValues, (err, docs) => {
    console.log(err); // null
    console.log(docs); // { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
    if (err) return cast.error(err);
    return cast.ok();
  });
```

However I receive `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }` in console log of `docs`
and `null` in console log of `err`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove this `let permission = new Permissions();`. No need to create new instance

Comment: That works. When should I make a new instance? When using save only?

Comment: so what changes were made to the code....... i am also getting the nModified: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**docs**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

> Models are fancy constructors compiled from Schema definitions. ***An
>   instance of a model is called a document***. Models are responsible for
>   creating and reading documents from the underlying MongoDB database.

So you need to create instance during the `.save()` call only. Other operations(update, read,  delete) applied on the existing document and hence, no need to create instance.

Comment: I faces a similar issue: my update gave me { n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }. My element was found but not update. This because I was using the instance of the schema object and not the schema itself. Thanks you very much.