# Deleting an element from an Array, that is inside an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, mongoose

In my To-Do app, when a logged-in User completes a task, I would like to clear it from the MongoDB database.

Here is the code for my Schema.

```
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    username : String,
    password : String,
    task : [{
        text : String,
        day : String,
        reminder : Boolean,
    ]}
 })
```

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM5Pt.png), if Daryl completed **text : "Gym" & day : "Feb 4th 5.30pm"**, I would like to only remove task[0] from Daryl's task Array.

Here is my attempt at doing so using Mongoose,

```
app.delete("/tasks", (req,res) => {
    User.findOne( {_id : req.user.id}).then((target) => {
        target.task.remove({text : req.body.text, day : req.body.day})
        })
})
```

1. User.findOne({_id : req.user.id}) to only target the person that logged in
2. Once targeted, access task array using .task
3. and use .remove along with filters, to remove that entry from the array

I have console.logged() all the variables and it tallies with the data fields, however the entry is not being removed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried saving the updated User document after removing the information?

Comment: I have tried adding target.save() / target.task.save() right after target.task.remove(), no changes as well. Tried changing target.task.remove to target.task.pull too

Comment: Perhaps try this. `User.updateOne( {_id : req.user.id }, { $pullAll: { text: req.body.text, day: req.body.day } } )`

Comment: Still no changes, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you get any error messages when using either the save() or updateOne() methods? Possibly add a callback to the `updateOne()` method such as this, and `console.log(err)` to see if there is an issue. `User.updateOne({ _id: req.user.id }, { $pullAll: { text: req.body.text, day: req.body.day } }, function(err, res) { console.log(err); console.log(res); });`

Comment: @WillWalsh I got an err message of null, and {ok:0, n:0, nModified:0}. I found someone with a similar error here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716535/mongoose-update-not-updating-ok-0-n-0-nmodified-0), but I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. How would I update the schema itself?

Comment: I tried User.findOneAndUpdate(.....), and it returned me a null error, and a res of {username : 'Testing', password : '$2abc' , ... }, basically all the fields of my document in MongoDB

Comment: Without seeing more code, I cannot help further. I would recommend inserting more `console.log` commands through the process to ensure things are happening as expected, and doing things in a step by step basis. Make the callback for `app.delete` async, and use `await`.

`app.delete("/tasks", aync (req,res) => {
    let user = await User.findOne( {_id : req.user.id})
    user.task.remove({...})
    console.log(user)
})`

See what that shows!?

Comment: I have double confirmed that (req.user.id) corresponds to _id, (req.body.text) corresponds to text field, and (req.body.day) corresponds to the day field through console.log. I tried console.log after user.task.remove as well, and the user.task still remained the same. I've also implemented async and await as well, and I tried removing the entire document by User.findOneAndDelete (at least that worked). Not really sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, hopefully this helps someone else

```
app.delete("/tasks", (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, {$pull: {"task": {text: req.body.text}}}, {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function (err, node) {
        // console.log here for debugging, if you want
        })
})
```

This successfully erases items based on

1. req.user.id
2. "task" : {//whatever your stricter conditions are}

I still don't understand why my earlier attempts failed, but at least this one works.