# How to update the data in existing document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update the data with in existing document and not create a other json document in the database. But its not modifing log is showing `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`..please help me thanks in advance

this is my code:

```
 const userUpdatedPassword = await UserPreferred.updateOne({_id: userPreferredExists._id},
 { 
   $push: {  
    languages: req.body.languages,
    storeType: req.body.storeType,
    intrestedIn: req.body.intrestedIn 
   }})
 }
```

i'm passing this data in postman:

```
{
"languages":["korean,"Hindi"],
"storeType":["gas station"],
"intrestedIn":["sarees"]
}
```

I've a json document in my db.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("60e968581871a42ab43a2345"), 
"languages" : [
    "English"
], 
"intrestedIn" : [
    "clothing", 
    "foot wear", 
    "watches",
], 
"storeType" : [
    "department stores", 
    "Medical stores"
]
}
```

I want in this fromat:-

```
 { 
  "_id" : ObjectId("60e968581871a42ab43a2345"), 
  "languages" : [
     "English",
     "korean,
     "Hindi"
  ], 
"intrestedIn" : [
    "clothing", 
    "foot wear", 
    "watches",
    "sarees"
  ], 
   "storeType" : [
     "department stores", 
     "Medical stores",
     "gas station"
   ]
   }
```

Comment: This answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716535/mongoose-update-not-updating-ok-0-n-0-nmodified-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose update not updating: { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716535/mongoose-update-not-updating-ok-0-n-0-nmodified-0)

Comment: no,  i'm already using `.save()` for new instance. but i already have an instance . so i want to push new elements in to existing json document

Comment: i find out the issue `userPreferredExists._id` is getting undefined so it is not updating

Comment: Try to remove userPreferredExists. and leave alone _id, and let me know the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query as your requirment, i have tried and tested at my local , One thing you have forgot to use closing quote language array for **korean**

```
const userUpdatedPassword = await UserPreferred.updateOne({_id: userPreferredExists._id},
 { 
   $push: {   
       languages: {
          $each:  req.body.languages
       },
      storeType: {
        $each:  req.body.storeType
      },
      intrestedIn: {
        $each: req.body.intrestedIn 
      }
   }
})
```

But this code will write duplicates in the array, so if you don't want to push duplicates in the array you can use `$addToSet` in place of `$push`, like following

```
const userUpdatedPassword = await UserPreferred.updateOne({_id: userPreferredExists._id},
 { 
   $addToSet: {   
       languages: {
          $each:  req.body.languages
       },
      storeType: {
        $each:  req.body.storeType
      },
      intrestedIn: {
        $each: req.body.intrestedIn 
      }
   }
})
```